# Android camera no save/discard button

Tags: c#, android, camera

I have been writing an application which uses the android camera object directly - not using the intent as I need more control over the resolution and other attributes.  I occasionally have an issue where by although I can take a picture I do not get the save and discard buttons displayed.  If I exit from the camera the last picture taken is returned to the calling activity but it is confusing as I need to process the photo and this does not work correctly unless save is clicked.  A reboot of the phone seems to clear the problem but I would like to identify why this happens...

Comment: what "save and discard" bittons are you talking about?

Comment: at the bottom of the camera in the preview screen there is normally a Save and a Discard button.  In some circumstances which I have not determined these buttons are not displayed and I have to use the 'back'button to get out of the camera activity.

Comment: Camera object has no Ui at all,  it doesnt even have its preview by itself - you have to set a SurfaceView to see anything